# How to overwrite a template in Magento

Tags: php, templates, magento, overwrite

I was following this answer,

https://[stackoverflow.com/questions/12936608/magento-howto-overwrite-one-template-file][1]

The file I'm trying to overwrite is,

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

I copied that file to

app/design/frontend/mycompany/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

I set,

System -> Configuration -> Design -> Package = mycompany

I flushed the buffer and refreshed and so forth, but

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

is still being used. According to the answers, this is supposed to overwrite the base template, but it doesn't. What do I need to do to make the Magento used the new register.phtml?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by modifying local.xml from,

```
<customer_account_login>
  <reference name="customer_form_login_1">
      <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>mycompany/login/login.phtml</template>
      </action>
      <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
      <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
   </reference>

   <reference name="root">
     <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/new-login.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>

    <reference name="content">
       <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login_new" template="mycompany/login/login.phtml" />
    </reference>

    <reference name="customer_form_login">
       <remove name="persistent.remember.me"/>
       <remove name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
       <remove name="customer_form_login"/>
    </reference>

</customer_account_login>
```

To the following,

```
<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="customer_form_login_1">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mycompany/login/login.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>mycompany/form/register.phtml</template></action>
    <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml"/>
    <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
       </reference>

   <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/new-login.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login_new" template="mycompany/login/login.phtml" />
    <block type="customer/form_register" template="mycompany/form/register.phtml" >
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
    <label>Form Fields Before</label>
    </block>
    </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="customer_form_login">
    <remove name="persistent.remember.me"/>
    <remove name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="customer_form_register">
    <remove name="persistent.remember.me"/>
    <remove name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
    <remove name="customer_form_login"/>
    <remove name="customer_form_register"/>
    </reference>

</customer_account_login>
```

and I copied app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml to app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mycompany/form/register.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will have to check which package and theme is using in frontend and then copied the file from

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml to the path

app/design/frontend/**mycompany/default**/template/customer/form/register.phtml

(which package is using on frontend. )

Comment: That is exactly what I did in my question.

Comment: 1) Have you create your own theme or third party theme

Comment: Yes, I wrote that in my question. That was the first thing I tried.